# What is the correct way to remove an entity and all of its collection data?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

In Eyeshot, what is the best way to remove an `Entity` from the `Model` that is a `BlockReference`?
Are there methods to help clean up all the `Blocks` based on `BlockReference`?

```
// assume "model1" is the Eyeshot control 

List<Entity> entities = GetEntitiesToRemove();
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
   if (entity is BlockReference reference)
   {
       // What to do here to clean up the associated blocks?  This code will only find the
       // parent block for the entity
       var block = model1.Blocks.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == reference.BlockName);
       if (block != null)
       {
           model1.Blocks.Remove(block);  //This is only removing the parent block 
       }
   }
   model1.Entities.Remove(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.Purge()` method: Removes unused items from the `Environment` master collections (Layers, Blocks, Materials, etc.)